# Why natural numbers are generalized in $\mathbb{Z}$ to ensure the group structure respect to the sum?

Tags: peano-axioms

> The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are defined through the Peano axioms and then generalized in $\mathbb{Z}$ to ensure the group structure with respect to the sum.

**Why do we need to ensure such group structure?**

The most complex structures are introduced in order to close the set with respect to the operations

$\mathbb{Z}$ closes $\mathbb{N}$ with respect to the sum
$\mathbb{Q}$ closes $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to the product
$\mathbb{R}$ includes the continuity axiom in $\mathbb{Q}$
$\mathbb{C}$ closes $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the roots of polynomials (fundamental theorem of algebra).

**How general method/set rules are used to close and why we need to 'close' ?**

Comment: **We do not need to ensure the group structure**.

Comment: More accurately, $\mathbb{Z}$ closes $\mathbb{N}$ with respect to *difference*. [Already closed with respect to sum.] Similarly should be quotient not product for $\mathbb{Q}.$ Your description for $\mathbb{R}$ is not the usual "completeness" axiom.

Comment: You are asking for an essay on the development of the concept of number. This is far too broad for MSE. I suggest you read the beautiful book [Numbers](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387974972). It will also help you with the technical glitches in your description of the relationships between the number systems.